# tocloft and babel (possible) incompatibility

Tags: babel, tocloft

I am trying to change the default section title for the TOC, renewing `tocloft`'s `\contentsname` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel} % (*) THE STARRED LINE

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{FooContents}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \section{The first section}
  \section{The second section}
\end{document}
```

If I remove the starred line, the TOC appears as expected, titled "FooContents" -- otherwise, the default title "Contents" is used.

Is there a way to get this done without getting rid of `babel`?

**EDIT**

Per @egreg's comment below, this particular issue can be solved with `\addto\captionsamerican{\renewcommand*{\contentsname{FooContents}}}`.

With regard to `\addto`, the `babel` [documentation](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf) (p. 64) states that:

> For each language four control sequences have to be defined that
>   control the language-specific definitions. To be able to add something
>   to these macro once they have been defined the macro \addto is
>   introduced.

However, I cannot find a list of those "four control sequences". I am using `tocloft` quite heavily, and most of what I do with it is reversed by `babel`.

Comment: `\addto\captionsamerican{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{FooContents}}`

Comment: But of course :-) However, I do not fully understand which macros I would need to renew like that. For instance, I am also changing the TOC title font (renewing `cfttoctitlefont`), but the above does not seem to work for that case.

Comment: In particular, `babel`'s documentation states about `\addto`: "For each language four control sequences have to be defined that control the
language-specific definitions. To be able to add something to these macro once they have
been defined the macro \addto is introduced." I've been browsing around the document to find these "four control sequences", but I cannot find a list.

Comment: Babel does not touch fonts, only names like `\contentsname` and friends